# StackExchange color icon in html

Tags: html, css, colors, icons, stackexchange

I'm trying my build my [personal webpage](http://nagabhushansn95.github.io/). I want to link to my stack exchange profile in my webpage using stack exchange icon. However the icons in font-awesome are grayscale (not color). I've colored other icons like LinkedIn, ORCID using CSS.

```
.color-linkedin {
    color: #0e76a8;
}
.color-orcid {
    color: #a6ce39;
}
```

But, StackExchange has shades of color. Is there something else that provided colored icon for SE? Or can I color it via CSS?

PS: Any other suggestions are also welcome. [My Repository](https://github.com/NagabhushanSN95/nagabhushansn95.github.io)

Comment: You could use the svg provided [here](https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg) instead. Since it is an SVG, you can grab its mark-up and place it within your code

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should change this property to change the color of the StackExchange icon:

```
.fa-stack-exchange:before {
                    content: "\f18d";
                    color: red;
}
```

As you said, the code above would change the whole icon, but basically you want to use gradient on your icon. I have done some research and found out what you need to do. You need to set these values:

```
.fa-stack-exchange:before {
          content: "\f18d";
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(FIRST COLOR, SECOND COLOR);
          -webkit-background-clip: text;
          -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Comment: That will make the entire icon red color. Instead I want the icon as [this](https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg) in the link by [Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons)

Comment: @NagabhushanSN what's the problem with the SVG, though?

Comment: @double_beep No problem. I was hoping if there is a direct solution. That is instead of downloading the image and having it in my repo.